# Why are spaces needed in the end of string array?

Tags: tex-core, source

In section 11 of `tex.web` is this:

```
@!pool_name='TeXformats:TEX.POOL                     ';
  {string of length |file_name_size|; tells where the string pool appears}
```

and in section 519 is this:

```
for k:=name_length+1 to file_name_size do name_of_file[k]:=' ';
```

Are these two pieces of code related? Why Pascal needs spaces in the end of string? And in which places in the code this fact is used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was a "feature" of standard Pascal that there was no universal "string" type, every length was a separate type. That is, "string of length 40" is a different type from "string of length 50"; a function can be declared to accept arguments of either one type or the other, not both. (In fact Pascal had no string type at all, it had arrays, for which the same problem applies: arrays of different lengths are different types.)

This used to be one of the most annoying things about programming with Pascal, and it was the main thing that Brian Kernighan (the "K" in "K&R" of the C programming language) complained about in his [“Why Pascal is Not My Favorite Programming Language”](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html) (written around the same time that Knuth was writing TeX in Pascal).

This inconvenience is the main reason that TeX does its own string handling (see [Part 4 / §38 onwards in the program](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=18)) (I'd started writing a bit about this [here](https://shreevatsa.github.io/tex/program/pooltype/)) -- mostly when it needs strings, it just uses an offset into a giant `str_pool` array of a pre-declared size, e.g. string `n` means whatever characters are in positions `str_start[n]` to `str_start[n+1] - 1` of the `str_pool` array.

But occasionally it needs to use strings that are actually arrays in Pascal, to pass to system calls or assign to variables for example. If you look at your string constant

```pascal
pool_name='TeXformats:TEX.POOL                     ';
```

the type of `pool_name` is not "string", but something like "an array of 40 chars". Later when `pool_name` is used ([§51](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=21)), in

```
name_of_file := pool_name;
```

the variable that it assigns to is of type (see [§26](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=12))

```
name_of_file : packed array [1 .. file_name_size] of char;
```

i.e. it's also an array of 40 characters, which is why the assignment is possible. This `name_of_file` is then passed to the system routines `reset` and `rewrite`, as seen in the next section §27 (and as explained in Marcel Krüger's answer).

---

Elsewhere in the program you'll see routines to convert TeX strings (i.e. consecutive positions of the `str_pool` array, as mentioned above), into Pascal strings, specifically into the Pascal string `name_of_file`. The `pack_file_name` of [section 519](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=189) you mention is one of those.

The idea is that if a string has been stored in a TeX string (e.g. when the user writes `\input foo.tex`, the `str_pool` array would contain the 7 characters `foo.tex`), then TeX would set `name_length` appropriately (here, 7) and then call this `pack_file_name` procedure, which will assign the Pascal string `name_of_file` to be `foo.tex` followed by spaces, so that `reset(..., name_of_file, ...)` can act on that string. If the characters were not cleared by adding spaces, then `reset` (as implemented by the Pascal-H runtime) could get an incorrect filename and try to open it.

[Note: Actually the format of file names was different and very inconsistent then, see Part 28: File names, [§511](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=187) onwards -- file names at Stanford had a "name", "extension", and "area" which might be something like `[1, DEK]`. So `pack_file_name` needs to combine these different TeX strings into a single Pascal string. But we can ignore that complication; the example of `foo.tex` is enough for this explanation.]

Answer (score 6):

In TeX, The Program there is a remark about this (directly after `name_of_file` is defined):

> 27. The Pascal-H compiler with which the present version of TEX was prepared has extended the rules of
>       Pascal in a very convenient way. To open file f , we can write
>
>     ```
>     reset (f , name ,  ́/O ́)      for input;
>     rewrite (f , name ,  ́/O ́)    for output.
>     ```
>
>     The ‘name ’ parameter, which is of type `packed array [<any>] of char`, stands for the name of the external
>       file that is being opened for input or output. Blank spaces that might appear in name are ignored.

Of course, this only seems to explain why the spaces are allowed, but why are they necessary?
The `<any>` in `packed array [<any>] of char` has to be filled with a *constant* number defined at *compile-time*, so the filename string has a compile-time defined length. But TeX does not want to restrict itself to opening files with a fixed length of the filename, therefore TeX by default defines a sufficiently large constant (40) which becomes the *maximal* length for a filename. Then a filename can be written to the first bytes of the field. The remaining bytes should be ignored, so they are filled with blanks.

Of course you might ask why Pascal-H reequires such a fixed length. I can only guess, but most likely this is to simplify porting to different systems. A variable sized string is relatively complicated to pass around: If often has to stored on the heap, different programming languages have different conventions of saving the length, etc. and the operating system might also enforce it's own conventions when passing the filename. On the other hand, a fixed size buffer is just a block of memory. It can be passed around freely, it can easily be allocated on the stack and some system specific code implemented in any language can parse it and transform it into the right format.

Also as Phelype mentioned, this often isn't very relevant for actual usage of TeX because it is in the system-specific part of the TeX sources. So for example in Web2C it is replaced by a implementation based on (C-style null-terminated) dynamic strings of length up to `maxint` and no spaces are written at the end of the names. (Instead, the code writes the `\0` terminator there)

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the `web2c` implementation changes that `40` character limit to `maxint`, which allows slightly longer file names ;-)

Comment: *why Pascal-H reequires such a fixed length. I can only guess, but most likely...* -- in fact the Pascal-H runtime's fs interfaces (like `reset` and `rewrite`) were special and did *not* require a fixed length; see the `<any>` in the `packed array [<any>] of char` you quoted (and §33 where a different length (4) is used). The explanation is simpler: Knuth wanted to pass `reset` and `rewrite` the same array `name_of_file` always, instead of declaring several different arrays, and arrays in Pascal had to be of a fixed length (whatever length was declared for `name_of_file` when it was declared).

Comment: Ah on rereading, I guess maybe you're saying the same thing as well, just differently. That is, in *"The `<any>` in `packed array [<any>] of char` has to be filled with a constant number defined at compile-time"* you don't mean that always the parameter to `reset` has to have the same length, but you just mean that in Pascal any given array needs to have a constant length at compile-time. And in *why Pascal-H reequires such a fixed length* you don't mean that Pascal-H's `reset` requires a fixed length but you're explaining why the Pascal language as a design choice chose fixed-length arrays.