# When a string may be assigned to an array?

Tags: tex-core, source

In section 51 of `tex.web` there is this:

```
name_of_file ← pool_name; { we needn’t set name length }
```

where `name_of_file` is (sectoin 26):

```
name_of_file : packed array [1 .. file name size ] of char;
```

and `pool_name` is (section 11):

```
pool_name = 'TeXformats:TEX.POOL                   ';
  { string of length file_name_size; tells where the string pool appears }
```

Is such string assignment a feature of Pascal? In which circumstances does Pascal allow to do string assignments? (like in section 51 above) Is the necessary condition that array and assigned string must have equal size?

*Similar case arises in sections 520 and 521.*

Comment: This isn't about TeX but about Pascal, so it belongs to StackOverflow IMO. Also a "feature of Pascal" is not really well-defined, especially since this code is older than any Pascal standard. But according to Standard Pascal, assignment of compatible string types is allowed (string types are compatible iff they have the same length)

Comment: Personally I think the question is fine here, or at least not appropriate for StackOverflow or any other generic site: Knuth was programming against a specific version of Pascal (Pascal-H), which people not closely connected with TeX may not have dug into the special characteristics of. (BTW, the standard of Pascal that existed at that time is *Pascal User Manual and Report* by Kathleen Jensen and Niklaus Wirth published in 1975; see §10.)

Comment: Anyway, I saw [the previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529220/why-are-spaces-needed-in-the-end-of-string-array) before seeing this, and I think my answer there happens to answer this as well (yes you can assign strings, i.e. arrays of chars, of the same length).

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, in the original (Wirth) Pascal this is exactly how it was designed: you could asign arrays of characters as long as they had the same range of indices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Pascal reference that Knuth used allows only assignments of
strings that have the same length. Strings in Pascal are arrays of
base type **char** with an *index type* that is a subrange of integers,
i.e., 1..n. And, of course, Knuth leaves no bytes unassigned. (That's why the *pool_name* gets *file_name_size* characters in your other question.)

In section 10 of `tex.web` Knuth states that he follows Jensen/Wirth's *User Manual & Report* of 1974; the original definition of the Pascal Language. He
made some exceptions---clearly indicated in situations where the
definition of the above mentioned book was obscure or clutter up the
code. For example, in the **case** statement he accepted an else/otherwise
part.

In the corrected printing of 1978 the book states on page 41 that a string with n>1 characters is a **packed array** [1..n] **of** char. The next sentence is ``Assignment (:=) is possible between operands of **identical** array types.''

I don't know much about the Pascal-H compiler that Knuth used. Later
Pascals, for example, the standard for Extended Pascal, allows more
flexible assignments for strings.

Comment: An **else** or **otherwise** extension of **case** was extremely common.

Comment: @vonbrand The extended case statement was available in many but not all Pascal implementations. That's why [section 10](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=5) ends with *"if no default mechanism is available, the case statements of TeX will have to be laboriously extended by listing all remaining cases. People who are stuck with such Pascals have, in fact, done this, successfully but not happily!"*. Also it was often available with a different syntax in each. (That's how I understand it, as I wrote [here](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-k/2019-December/003094.html).)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I just read your answer for the previous question. You're right, it answers this question too.

Comment: @vonbrand You are right such an extension was common. But as ShreevatsaR states in the above comment there was no universal solution at the time when Knuth did the programming how the **case** statement should be extended. `The User Manual and Report` defines **case** without a default case.